# Launch a graphical application with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, display

I have a simple command to run a java file (power architect) application with graphical interface in a docker container.

`sudo docker run --rm --net=host --env="DISPLAY" --name cont_sql_power_architect -it -v $HOME/Desktop/FRM_project/volumes/sql_power_architect:/project img_sql_power_architect java -jar project/architect-1.0.8/architect.jar &`

I try to reproduce it in docker-compose

```
services:     
  sql_power_architect:    
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles/
      dockerfile: dockerfile_sql_power_architect
    image: img_sql_power_architect
    container_name: cont_sql_power_architect
    environment:
      - DISPLAY
    network_mode: "host"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/sql_power_architect:/project
    command: 
      - java -jar project/architect-1.0.8/architect.jar &
```

When I launch the `docker-compose up -d`, the container is launched but instantaneously stopped. The commands seems to be the same than the docker run. I don't see what I am missing.
Any Idea ?

PS to be able to run with a docker run, I have to execute before the command `xhost +"local:docker@"` each time I open a new console. But I still execute it before the docker-compose command.

Comment: I fact when I use `docker-compose up` without the "-d". I obtain the error message

> cont_sql_power_architect | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 315: /java -jar project/architect-1.0.8/architect.jar: No such file or directory. 

When I go inside the container I find the file at the exact place. It seems that the docker-compose execute the entrypoint command before it mount the volume !? I am lost

Comment: Does it work better if you move the `java -jar ...` immediately after `command:`, and remove the `-` at the beginning and `&` at the end?

Comment: Oh thank you very much it works. There are other problems, but the command is not ignored anymore!